# Can a straight line be considered a part of a circle?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Say we have a circle of infinite radius. If we zoom in infinitely on its perimeter, we should end up looking at a straight line. Intuitively. But, such a line, I believe, should have a curvature of $1/∞$. But a straight line is defined to have $0$ curvature in Euclidean geometry. My interpretation also has problems if we consider parallel lines. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: What does "circle of infinite radius" even mean?

Comment: "Zooming in infinitely" : you really need to make things more precise.

Comment: Um, if I was looking at a part of the perimeter of a circle on a flat plane, and then kept increasing the radius such that it tended to infinity, while keeping my view fixed on the portion I was observing, wouldn't it converge to a straight line?

Comment: "tending to infinity" is not "equal to infinity".  It will "tend" to a straight line.  But it will never achieve it.  And it will never achieve infinite radius either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"circle of infinite radius"

Meaningless.

"If we zoom in infinitely"

Meaningless.

"we should end up looking at a straight line"

A straight line that is a magnification of a single point.  Which is meaningless.

$\infty$ is not a number or a value. It is a concept to describe values that may be arbitrarily large and have no upper bound.

All circles have finite radius.  But for any value $M$ we can have a circle with radius $> M$.  So the radius becomes large the curvature becomes smaller.  We state that as $\lim_{r\to \infty} Curvature (r) = 0$ (and similarly $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1x = 0$).  But that does not mean infinite radius or $0$ curvature or $\frac 1 {\infty}$ ever occur.  They don't and can't.

But yes for a circle with extremely huge radius will have extremely small curvature and the arcs will become arcs that differ from a line segments only very slightly.  But it is never infinite radius or zero curvature.  And although the arc will differ from straight lines only minisculely, they will differ.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't. A straight line can't be considered as part of a circle.

I can remember from my algebra class (long time ago), that at some point we had to take the limit of $x$ to zero. And the teacher was screaming: **we never get to zero** (my ears are still ringing). To give you an example, for $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ we have:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty,
$$
but $f(x)$ **does not exist** for $x=0$.